# Powershell - Get Data of Registry Value Saved to a Variable

Tags: powershell

I need to save a single data item in a registry key to a variable. I've tried the following without any luck:

```
$dxVersion = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX").GetValue("Version",$null)
```

I want JUST the version number saved to the variable, nothing else. Not the name, just the data.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You almost had it. Try:

```
$dxVersion = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX").Version
```

[Get-ItemProperty](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849851.aspx) returns a PSCustomObject with a number of properties -- Version among them. This sort of dotted notation as I used above allows you to quickly access the value of any property.

Alternatively, [so long as you specify a scalar property](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/09/14/select-expandproperty-propertyname.aspx), you could use the ExpandProperty parameter of `Select-Object`:

```
$dxVersion = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version
```

Comment: Thanks! Used the first way, seems easier. Is there an advantage to using the second method?

Comment: @Fro Yeah, the first way is easier for your situation.  If the output within the parenthesis is a collection and the property is not, you can use `-ExpandProperty` to retrieve the value of the specified property from each object in the collection.